# UITableView: how stop selection while swipe the table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have swipe to delete code here and it my custom TableViewCell I have implemented setSelected method like below ..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
       // tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false
        if tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil, tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath {
            return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.none
        }
        return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete
    }
```

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        //some code here 
}
```

The logic will do tableview expand collapse based on selection ..but the problem here is if I swipe to delete setSelected also triggers.. not sure how to prevent that any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cellForRow

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_identifier", for: indexPath)                
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
    //or this based on swift version 
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the appearance you are going for but this will produce the same effect.

If swipe is across the whole screen it will trigger the delete without button press.

If half swipe you can present buttons for user to choose options.

Half swipe (Shows options):

[image]

Full swipe (Triggers delete button):

[image]

Try adding these two `tableView` delegate methods for a swipe to delete

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Determine which rows should be editable
    return true
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: 
    IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        
    let button1 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { 
        action, indexPath in
        print("delete pressed")
        // Consider alert to confirm that it was intentionally deleted
    }
    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    // Create any buttons you want

    return [button1]
        
}
```

I tried it with and without your tableView method and it seemed to work fine both ways but I don't think your method is necessary if you choose this route

Hope this helps